# Why Composer require jquery installs unwanted PHP packages?

Tags: php, jquery, composer-php

I just wanted jQuery and entered in the command line 
`composer require components/jquery ^1.11`

But the log shows me:

```
Package operations: 4 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.2.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing robloach/component-installer (0.2.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing components/jquery (1.11.0): Loading from cache
```

Why does Composer install PHP related packages I never intended to install? And how do I get rid of the unwanted packages? Is there an better/cleaner install method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to install on of `1.11` versions of a package, which is requires `"robloach/component-installer"` package to install , you can see that clearly [here](https://github.com/components/jquery/blob/1.11.0/composer.json) :

```
"require": {
        "robloach/component-installer": "*"
},
```

however, `robloach/component-installer` requires some additional packages too,
also you can see that [here](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer/blob/master/composer.json)

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.*",
        "composer-plugin-api": "^1.0"
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation. Could you tell me how I can install only pure jQuery without dependences? Is it possible at all?

Comment: `composer require components/jquery` will install -till this time- the version 3.2 which does not need any dependencies to require , https://github.com/components/jquery/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: Thanks Hassan! ;)